# Can't run ltx2any from Texstudio (Windows)

Tags: compiling, texstudio

I'm trying to get ltx2any running with TexStudio under Windows 10. I have ltx2any installed in "D:\Programs\Office\Latex\ltx2any", and put the folder in the PATH environment. Running "ltx2any" on a *.tex file in a command prompt works fine. However, if I try to configure a user command in TexStudio, such as

> "D:/Programs/Office/Latex/ltx2any/ltx2any" -synctex -c %

I just get the following error:

> Error: Could not start the command: "D:/Programs/Office/Latex/ltx2any/ltx2any" -synctex -c "file"

I've tried various versions of the user command, with and without the path to the file, or pointing it to ltx2any.rb, but none of these seem to allow me to run ltx2any from within TexStudio. Does anybody have any helpful tips for how to resolve this?

Comment: I don't use `ltx2any` but is there no file extension?

Comment: Indeed there isn't, but the version with an extension produces the same error:

> "D:/Programs/Office/Latex/ltx2any/ltx2any" -synctex -c %.tex

So it seems to be about calling ltx2any, not about pointing it to the right file.

Comment: Can you run `ltx2any` directly in the folder using the command window?

Comment: Yes, I can, but having to run it manually every time instead of using a shortcut within TexStudio would kind of defeat the purpose. :)

Comment: I just asked to be sure that is works in general, nothing more.